# Good way to reduce number of colors in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, compression

I have pages of handwritten notes that I decided to scan to a PDF. Somehow, 153 pages of notes turned into a 156.4 MB PDF file.

The notes are scanned in color because I used four different colors: black, red, blue, green. In fact, the only colors I really need for the document are those four (plus white). Is there a way to reduce the number of colors in the PDF file? (e.g. via a Unix command?)

Comment: It might be a better idea to lower the resolution instead of messing with the colors.

Comment: @ZippyV, under which circumstances would it be a better idea to degrade the resolution instead of reducing the unnecessary colour depth?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/).

PDFs use color depth, which may somewhat limit you in terms of specifying the ***exact*** number of colors you would like to use, however, that doesn't mean you won't be able to reduce the file size.

For -depth Ghostscript uses values of:

```
1 (black & white), 8 (256 colors) and 24 (true color)
```

Some possible options to help reduce the file size:

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen   (screen-view-only quality, 72 dpi images)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook    (low quality, 150 dpi images)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer  (high quality, 300 dpi images)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress (high quality, color preserving, 300 dpi imgs)
-dPDFSETTINGS=/default  (almost identical to /screen)
```

→ [example script](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I looked at http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm and could not find how to set the depth. (I tried the example script with `-depth=1` added and that did not make the output black and white.)

Answer (score 0):

for color texts, djvu is better in compression, try to extract scanned images from pdf and compress in a djvu file with

**djvusolo**

- http://www.tuberadio.it/utils.htm

djvusolo works very well with wine in Linux

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising that there still doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. I have also been looking for a solution for years.

You can get relatively far with [PDF-XChange Editor (free version)](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor). PDF XChange Editor allows to export a PDF to, for example, multipage TIFF, with precise control of resolution and color depth, inter alia.

Unfortunately, the images are almost always resampled, unless you catch a combination of page zoom and resolution that results in exactly the same pixel size of the images that are embedded in the original PDF.

Anyway, the TIFF can be easily opened with PDF-XChange Editor afterwards and then re-saved as PDF again.

[image: PDF-XChange Editor "Exort to Images"]